# What was the duration of the exclusive right granted to rizla+ over this patent?

Tags: patent-infringement, licensing, expiration, legal-status

In reference to the patent: [US4985302](https://www.google.com/patents/US4985302)

Answer (score 0):

This patent likely expired on June 3, 2008, according to the USPTO patent term calculator.  You can calculate patent term using the USPTO's patent term calculator available at: https://www.uspto.gov/patent/laws-and-regulations/patent-term-calculator#heading-1

There are foreign counterparts that may still be in force as I didn't look at them, damages for past infringement may be available for up to six years after the expiration of the patent depending on many details.